# How to add chars to 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

My code:

```
FILE * file;

file = fopen("c://catalog//file.txt", "r");
int m,n; //size of 2d array (m x n)
fscanf(file, "%d", &m);
fscanf(file, "%d", &n);
fclose(file);

printf("Size: %d x %d\n", m, n);

// create 2d array 
char **TAB2 = new char*[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    char *TAB2 = new char[n];

// display 2d array 
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("%c ", &TAB2[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

How fill this array with chars or string? for example text = "someting", and for array 3x5 will be:

```
S o m e t
h i n g ?
? ? ? ? ?
```

I tried: TAB2[0][0] = 's'; *&TAB2[0][0] = 's'; for one char, and this does'nt work...

Probably I badly use pointers(?). Anyone help me?

Comment: i corrected, this should be 'file'

Comment: The bad use of pointers is *using* them here.

Comment: The part inside your for loop used to allocate memory for each row of character is already wrong. Should be something like TAB2[i] = new char[n]; or advance the pointer *TAB2 every time you allocate a new char array

Comment: The printing stuff is also wrong. You are passing an address to printf instead of a character. (i.e. remove the &)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic allocation array is wrong.

```
char **TAB2 = new char*[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    TAB2[i] = new char[n];
```

Check this [link](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/dynamic-2d-array-in-c/) for help.

---

You could try this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  const int m = 3, n = 5;
  char **TAB2 = new char*[m];
  for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
      TAB2[i] = new char[n];

  char c;
  for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      std::cin >> c;
      TAB2[i][j] = c;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      std::cout << TAB2[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }

  // NEVER FORGET TO FREE YOUR DYNAMIC MEMORY
  for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    delete [] TAB2[i];
  delete [] TAB2;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
jorje
georg
klouv
jorje
georg
klouv
```

---

Important links:

1. [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936702/2411320)
2. [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new/936702#936702 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Comment: Oh here is my pic in the first link @sehe! haha. By the way, good links, I am editing.

Comment: You are welcome @adfgvx. Make sure you take a look at the links in my question!

Comment: @G.Samaras fix the first delete :-)

Comment: A bug @Diego? Tell me more please.

Comment: I think it should use the `delete[]` operator as the memory was allocated with `new[]`.

Comment: Yeah! Nice catch @Diego. Damn you are good! I am gonna upvote an answer of yours for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983244/is-this-deallocation-correct

Answer (score 2):

The allocation of the array seems incorrect; it should be as follows.

```
char **TAB2 = new char*[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    TAB2[i] = new char[n];
```